# GFCI has power but outlet doesnt work

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

Im installing an exterior gfci. It comes from the breaker to a juntion box, to the exterior box. Inside i have a 20amp single pole switch controlling the gfci. Its supposed to be for running power tools and Christmas lights. I have power in the box. The gfci is lit. I can test it and reset it by pressing its buttons. Works fine in that aspect. When I touch the side screws with a tic test, it lights up and beeps. But when I try to tic test the hot slot on the outlet nothing happens. I tried plugging power tools into it. Still no sign of power. I plugged one of those gfci testers that tell you how your wiring might be bad with the different lights on it and the gfci tester built into it - nothing. If the wiring was bad it would light up and indicate which way its bad. I switched the gfci with another. Same brand, same supply, exactly the same bought it the same day. It did the same thing.

I have gfci/afci 20amp breaker. From there 12/2 to a juction box where its wire nutted to 12/2 type uf to go outside. Hot wire goes to the switch and then to the gfci line side. Neutral and ground straight to gfci, neutral on white on the line side. Ive had devices fail in the past, but two in a row? Any ideas?

Comment: What make and model is the GFCI, and why are you putting a GFCI receptacle on a GFCI breaker?

Comment: There is some warning tape covering some stuff on the GFCI. Was that removed or is it still there?

Comment: There is warning tape covering the load side. I am somewhat of a professional. Its a mansion. I dont want to have to run all the way down to the garage if the breaker trips. An if they aren't home... The guy is having a lot of work done to the house but has zero exterior receptacles. I was told by other electricians make sure I use gfci/afci breakers. I wasn't going to. I was just gonna piggyback off the laundry room breaker. Im going to try a regular outlet but I'm kinda worried when I pulled the uf cable through the brick masonry it may of been knicked on the metal supports in the brick.

Comment: I brought the gfi receptacle home and wired it to a 15 amp circuit and it worked fine.

Comment: Legrand 2097TRWRW

Comment: When you test with the tic tester is the brass colored side lighting and the silver screw not lighting?   Second with power on from the switch try test and reset (some GFCI’s) have to be reset after power failure , turn the switch off test and reset are need to get the receptacle or if used the load terminals to be reenergized.

Comment: Why are you trying to piggyback off the laundry room circuit? That circuit can't have any other outlets on it, as per NEC 210.11(C)(2)....

Answer (score 0):

You must not have power on you feed wires. If your neutral is open, you will still get 'tic' on the hot. Also, you can get false tics (they are very sensitive). They can pic up induced or field charges. Try a neon or DVM on the supply wires. Try a real load (like a pigtail bulb). You may need to abandon that UF if it's damaged, and/if grouted into the brickwork.

Not sure if code requires laundry to have it's own circuit (and not branched out to more outlets).

Confirm you have power (and neutral) first, and go from there...

Mr K L